# Installing "scripts" in setup.py as part of a Python package, on user's path and recognized as Python scripts

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, distutils

I'm trying to have a Python script available on a user's path when they install my package from PyPI using `pip`:

```
pip install MyPackage
```

`MyPackage` is on PyPI and installs successfully--apparently--in a `conda` virtual environment. The `setup.py` file (excerpted) looks like this:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'name': 'MyPackage',
    'version': '0.2.1.dev',
    'install_requires': [...],
    'packages': [
        'MyPackage', 'MyPackage.utils'
    ],
    'py_modules': [
        'MyCLI',
    ],
    'scripts': [
        'MyPackage/MyCLI.py',
    ],
...
```

On GNU/Linux, when I type `MyCLI` and hit Tab, it successfully auto-completes to `MyCLI.py`. When I ask `which MyCLI.py` it shows me the fully qualified path to Python script in the virtual environment folder:

```
$ which MyCLI.py
/home/arthur/Applications/miniconda3/envs/MyPackage/bin/MyCLI.py
```

`MyCLI.py` uses [`fire`](https://github.com/google/python-fire) to wrap a Python class, expose its methods at the command line, present docstrings as help documentation, and parse arguments. It looks like:

```py
'''
My Command Line Interface
'''

class CLIRuntime(object):
    def run(self):
        do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import fire
    fire.Fire(CLIRuntime)
```

If I run this script with the Python interpreter, it executes correctly.

```
python $(which MyCLI.py)
```

**The problem is, when I try to run it without specifying the Python interpreter, it seems to think it is a bash script or binary file and wrecks my terminal session:**

```sh
$ MyCLI.py
/home/arthur/Applications/miniconda3/envs/MyPackage/bin/MyCLI.py: line 8:
My Command Line Interface
: No such file or directory
from: can't read /var/mail/__future__
```

**How can I change `setup.py` so that this script is available on a user's path but also known as/ runs as a Python script?**

I want to note that if I install this package from source using `pip` in editable mode (`pip install -e .`), `MyCLI.py` is on my path and runs correctly as a Python script. It just doesn't appear to work when installing from PyPI.

Comment: Can't you just add `#!python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line?

Comment: @MattDMo That might be it. Want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell your shell what program should be used to execute a script file, you need to add a "hash-bang" declaration *as the first line* in the script. For Python executing inside of a virtualenv, either

```sh
#!python
```

or

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

will do the trick. If you're using Python 3, use `python3` instead.